# Changing boarding point for advance UK train tickets

Tags: uk, trains, tickets, london

I'm supposed to be taking a friend to Edinburgh in a few days, we booked advance tickets with LNER from Kings Cross to Edinburgh together using their disabled persons railcard.
I was supposed to meet them in London, they are holding both tickets and we're going to give me mine when we met, but it now seems I won't be able to get there in time for a number of reasons. However, I can get to York, which is a stop couple of hours into the journey. 
As my friend hold both tickets and the railcard, can they board the train in London, and I board later in York using my planned ticket? 
There are no ticket barriers so my only issue boarding is with the ticket inspector on the train.
Is this allowed or should we attempt to amend the booking?

The emphasis is on the use of the disabled persons railcard. It gives 1/3 off the cost for both tickets as they were bought together. Ordinarily advance tickets are inflexible, but here one person (the card holder) will complete the entire journey and occupy the reserved seats, while only the second person will board the train later.

Comment: I have a feeling that if the 'accompanying person' of someone using a disabled railcard has benefited from the one-third discount, that person must travel with the disabled person for the whole of the journey. Thus if the disabled card holder starts the journey alone, the discounted ticket held by the other person becomes invalid at that point.

Comment: What do the LNER Terms & Conditions say?

Comment: Disabled Railcard conditions are set nationally, not by individual train companies.

Comment: Well, that was easy. The T&C are here: https://www.disabledpersons-railcard.co.uk/help/railcard-terms-conditions/ Section 4.1 says "Only you and, where appropriate, the adult accompanying you, can use discounted tickets. The accompanying adult must travel with you throughout the journey." So in this case, the answer is "You must take the entire journey as booked. If you cannot take the entire journey as booked, you must either amend the booking, or abandon the booking and make a new booking.".